# has_many :through Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many-through

I want to set a reservation based on user_id and trip_id . but i dont know how to . I tried to make a form in trips/show

What i want is to see the full list of trips and select one  and the form below should save the user_id and trip_id in databse. Idk if i can send data like this because i wrote the form in trips which has his own model of Trip.
Can someone explain how has_many :through concept work. The problem is that idk if i can make another controller to save ids or i can do it in trip controllers. please help

```
<h1>Trips</h1>

<table class="table ">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>Locatie</th>
      <th>Descriere</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <%=  Current.user.admin %>
  <% if Current.user.admin == true %>
    <tbody>
       
      <% @trips.each do |trip| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= trip.locatie %></td>
          <td><%= trip.descriere %></td>
          <td class="text-center"><%= link_to 'Select', trip , class: "btn btn-secondary "%></td>
         
          <td class="text-center"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_trip_path(trip) ,class: "btn btn-secondary " %></td>
          <td class="text-center"><%= link_to 'Destroy', trip, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } ,class: "btn btn-secondary "%></td>
          
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  <% else %>
   <tbody>
       
      <% @trips.each do |trip| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= trip.locatie %></td>
          <td><%= trip.descriere %></td>
          <td class="text-center"><%= link_to 'Select', trip , class: "btn btn-secondary "%></td>
         
        
          
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
    <% end %>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Trip', new_trip_path ,class:"btn btn-secondary"%>
```

```
<p>
  <strong>Locatie:</strong>
  <%= @trip.locatie %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Descriere:</strong>
  <%= @trip.descriere %>
</p>


<%= @trip.id %>
<%= Current.user.id %>
<br/>




<%= form_with model: @reservation, local: true , url: save_reservation_path do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :user_id ,  value: @trip.id %>
  <%= form.text_field :trip_id ,  value: Current.user.id%>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>




<%= link_to 'Back', trips_path ,class: "btn btn-secondary "%>
```

Trip controller

```
class TripsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_trip, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /trips or /trips.json
  def index
    @trips = Trip.all
  end

  # GET /trips/1 or /trips/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /trips/new
  def new
    @trip = Trip.new
  end

  # GET /trips/1/edit
  def edit
  end


 
  # POST /trips or /trips.json
  def create
    @trip = Trip.new(trip_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @trip.save
        format.html { redirect_to trip_url(@trip), notice: "Trip was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @trip }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @trip.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /trips/1 or /trips/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @trip.update(trip_params)
        format.html { redirect_to trip_url(@trip), notice: "Trip was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @trip }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @trip.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /trips/1 or /trips/1.json
  def destroy
    @trip.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to trips_url, notice: "Trip was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end


 
  
  

  
  

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_trip
      @trip = Trip.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def trip_params
      params.require(:trip).permit(:locatie, :descriere)
    end
   
   
end
```

Reservation controller

```
class ReservationsController < ApplicationController
  

  # GET /reservations or /reservations.json
  def index
    @reservations = Reservation.all
  end

  # GET /reservations/1 or /reservations/1.json
  def show
    @reservations = Reservation.all
  end

  # GET /reservations/new
  def new
    @reservation = Reservation.new
  end

  # GET /reservations/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /reservations or /reservations.json
  def create
    @reservation = Reservation.new(reservation_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @reservation.save
        format.html { redirect_to reservation_url(@reservation), notice: "Reservation was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @reservation }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @reservation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /reservations/1 or /reservations/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @reservation.update(reservation_params)
        format.html { redirect_to reservation_url(@reservation), notice: "Reservation was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @reservation }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @reservation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /reservations/1 or /reservations/1.json
  def destroy
    @reservation.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to reservations_url, notice: "Reservation was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_reservation
      @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def reservation_params
    params.require(:reservation_params).permit(user_id: [], trip_id: [])
    end
end
```

Comment: I don't want to be rough, but you probably need to sum up and have a more concise question + code especially if you are looking for a rapid and clear answer

The better the question is, the better the answer

Comment: Agreed. Also, for a `has_many ... , through: ...` question you'd want to post the models. Essentially though, if a reservation belongs to a trip and a trip belongs to a user, then a reservation belongs to a user without the need for `user_id` on the reservations table. You can then call `reservation.user` and Rails finds the user via reservation.trip_id --> trip.user_id.